# ansible conditional templates

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I want to have a simple if else condition in ansibles jinja templates. For plain python

```
cluster_name+'A' if isCondition is True else cluster_name +'B'
```

wors great if the following variables are defined:

```
isSingleNode = True
cluster_name = 'example'
```

In ansible I see the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: no test named 'True'. String: {\n\n   \"key\" : \"{{ groups[cluster_name+'_mn01' if isSingleNode is True else cluster_name + '_mn02'] }}\"\n}\n"}
```

Here is a minimal example:

file_1: variables

```
---
isCondition: True
```

file_2: playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_vars: variables
    - debug: msg=" condition is {{ isCondition }} with cluster_name {{ cluster_name }}"

    - name: copy file
      template: src="bare_cluster.bp.j2" dest={{ cluster_name }}_blueprint.json backup=yes
```

file_4: inventory

```
[examplecluster:children]
examplecluster_mn01

[mn01:children]
examplecluster_mn01

[examplecluster_mn01]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

file_5: bare_cluster.bp.j2

```
{

   "key" : "{{ groups[cluster_name+'_mn01' if isSingleNode is True else cluster_name + '_mn02'] }}"
}
```

command to execute the minimal example is `ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -e 'cluster_name=examplecluster'`

Comment: @downvoter please explain why.

Comment: You can't write arbitrary python code in **jinja2** expression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you try?

```
{% if isCondition %} {{ cluster_name }} A {% else %} {{ cluster_name }} B {% endif %}
```